# C# Win App, Task Scheduler, User Account: System. Microsoft Excel cannot access the file

Tags: c#, excel, windows-task-scheduler

I have Task Scheduler on a Windows server; the User Account is System. This task starts a .NET windows app that reads an Excel file, but it shows the error:

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'D:\Automation\02_14_25_.xlsx'
> There are several possible reasons:
>
> - The file name or path does not exist.
> - The file is being used by another program.
> - The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

I created the folder Desktop in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile` and `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\` but still same error.

When I log in to the server as myself(administrator) and run the app, it runs without errors.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: %SystemRoot% (ie: C:\Windows) is a protected directory (as well as folders beneath it) and requires administrative privileges.

Answer (score 3):

You did not clarify that the file: "D:\Automation\02_14_25_.xlsx"

Actually exists or if that is just the error message you could not correctly interpret.

In that case my answer would be:
Your application is not started with the correct environment variables if it runs as a scheduled task. That is my classical mistake for the:

"It works when i run it manually but it doesn't when i do it with cron/scheduled task." - Scenario

Comment: The file does exists. No arguments/parameters are needed. When I run it manually, I just double click the exe file. Thanks

Comment: I see that you did something quite helpful, and although you're right that this should maybe be a comment, I gave you an upvote so you can make helpful comments in the future.

Comment: This answer didn't provide any help. I'm still unable to open/read the Excel file.

Comment: Have you tried running it as a regular (administrative) user? Some applications refuse to run as system user. Also iam confused as to why you created a folder named Desktop at the named locations. That seems pretty random so we are likely missing some vital information.